# Duplicate users in mysql.user

Tags: mysql

I just did a SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user; and I get the following results :

```
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host                                | User     | Password                                  |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost                           | root     | *CFB0F01E12976D94C46201145940E3EF71E32742 |
| my_name_goes_here-MacBook-Pro.local | root     | *CFB0F01E12976D94C46201145940E3EF71E32742 |
| 127.0.0.1                           | root     | *CFB0F01E12976D94C46201145940E3EF71E32742 |
| ::1                                 | root     | *CFB0F01E12976D94C46201145940E3EF71E32742 |
| localhost                           |          |                                           |
| my_name_goes_here-MacBook-Pro.local |          |                                           |
| %                                   | testuser | *00E247AC5F9AF26AE0194B41E1E769DEE1429A29 |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

How do I remove these duplicate entries?
(I can also see the previous version of mysql(5.5.8) in my hard drive)

Comment: there are no duplicate entries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no duplicate entries. There is one row for each Host/User combination. But if you do need to remove one, have a look at [DROP USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-user.html)

**Addition to answer**

This query will show you that the empty users actually have a '' name:

```
SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user WHERE User LIKE '';
```

This means they can be removed with:

```
DROP USER ''@'localhost';
DROP USER ''@'my_name_goes_here-MacBook-Pro.local';
```

Do make sure you really want to remove them though. Maybe there are some processes that need them to be there and connect using these different hostnames.

Comment: But be careful not to drop them all.

Comment: I mean the localhost and my_name_goes_here-MacBook=Pro.local rows that have no password

Comment: Yes, but their `User` values are empty as well, making them *not duplicate*.

Comment: Is there a way to drop only the two users that have no password?

Comment: I just added the queries on how to remove them. Do make sure you actually want to remove them though!